# Why doesn't <Table/> show the check box when rendered multiple times?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I am using `<Table/>` from http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/table . When I render the `<TableRowColumn/>` multiple times depending on how many objects are in the array, the checkboxes do not appear. For example, if there are two objects, it renders two rows, but the checkboxes don't show. What may be the issue?

**COMPLETELY NEW EDIT**

So the `FileTable.js` is rendered on another page, and it is triggered to be made by a button inside an index route `Home.js`.

```
render(
  <div>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route
          component={RequireAuth(App)}
          path='App'
        >
          <IndexRoute
            component={Home}
          />
          <Route
            component={FileTable}
            path='/FileTable'
          />
        </Route>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

And `App.js` is:

```
class App extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
        <div>
          {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.props)}
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I followed exactly how you implemented and got the correct property `queryVehicles`, yet when I pressed the button on `Home.js` now I got the following error:

[image]

Comment: Do you see any error in the console? Ca you show an exerpt of the row data?

Comment: @Pandaiolo No errors but I got warnings. Not sure if they are problems though cause they usually pop up with Material-UI but haven't caused any problems. Updated the original post with the warnings and excerpt of the row data.

Comment: @Pandaiolo Please let me know if you had the chance to see the comment

Comment: Do you use the last versions of react and material-ui ? The warning seem related to your problem, you should investigate to resolve them.

Comment: @Pandaiolo How can I update to the latest version?

Comment: `npm view material-ui` to see the versions avaiable, `npm list material-ui` to see your installed version, `npm install -S material-ui@^0.15.4` to install last stable version asof oct 10, 2016 (soon it will be 0.16.0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the browser warnings you are receiving, it sounds like you have a distinct React component encapsulating the `TableRow` ("`FileTableRow`").

When you iterate over some data in the `TableBody`, you will see different behavior between using `TableRow` in-line (like in your code snippet) and a separate component (like `<FileTableRow />`), with regards to checkbox behavior.

With the current implementation of `TableBody` and `TableRow`, if you want to have a separate `FileTableRow` component, you need to have it as follows in order for the checkbox to appear.

```
const FileTableRow = (props) => {
  const { children, Date, Start_Time, End_Time, Type, ...rest } = props

  // The checkbox element will be inserted by the <TableBody> as a child
  // of this component. So if we have a separate row component like this,
  // we need to manually render it from the props.children

  // We also use {...rest} to pass any other props that the parent <TableBody />
  // passed to this component. This includes any handlers for the checkbox.
  return (
    <TableRow {...rest}>
      {children[0]}
      <TableRowColumn>{Date}</TableRowColumn>
      <TableRowColumn>{Start_Time}</TableRowColumn>
      <TableRowColumn>{End_Time}</TableRowColumn>
      <TableRowColumn>{Type}</TableRowColumn>
    </TableRow>
  )
}
```

Also, the warnings sound like you are wrapping the `<TableRow />` components in a `<div />`, which should be avoided.

Edit:

Added usage of `{...rest}` to pass on any other props to the `<TableRow>`

Added a working example at: http://www.webpackbin.com/4kNnhM2o-

Edit 2:

Added a modified example with what seems to more closely match the asker's data structure. http://www.webpackbin.com/VkuA-FbhZ

Edit 3:

Made the component stateful to capture and log selected rows. Due to some quirks with their `Table` implementation, needed to turn the `Table` into a controlled component. http://www.webpackbin.com/EyhKEDNhb

Comment: Sorry but before I accept the answer and upvote it, could you show with the .map, with props being passed to the FileTableRow component? I tried but can't seem to understand the logic and get it to work.

Comment: Also I temporarily got it to work, but the checkbox doesn't get checked off when clicked on. Is something else need to be added?

Comment: Just checking to see if you've seen my previous comment. Please let me know

Comment: Hi @JoKo, I added one change to ensure the checkbox functionality is there, and added a link to a working live example.

Comment: Thought I responded and was waiting for yours, so I checked back today and looks like the comment is gone... I updated the original post with code, please take a look. The checkbox still does not work, what could be the issue?

Comment: @JoKo, 1. Based on your most recent edit, it looks like your data has two levels of nesting (there are multiple **vehicles** and each vehicle has multiple **files**). Please let me know if my understanding is wrong.  If this is the case, then you need to flatten your data in the parent component such that each `FileTableRow` is for one **File**. 2. And also, the `FileTableRow` needs to have the `TableRow` be the wrapper tag, not a `div`.   Please look at the working demo link in my answer to see if that helps explain that second bit about my second point.

Comment: @JoKo, I made a new example with what I think more closely matches the data shape you are working with (from what I piece together in your code samples). http://www.webpackbin.com/VkuA-FbhZ

Comment: Your assumption is correct! Thank you so much for making the revision and clarification. A few questions, why const FileTableRow over class FileTableRow? And also why .forEach over .map?

Comment: In the example, the `FileTableRow` is implemented as a React Functional Component (instead of an ES6 class) since it is purely presentational. It doesn't matter that much (if you're interested in guidelines of when to use what, you can search for "react dumb vs smart components").  And for your second question, again it doesn't matter that much how you transform your data. I decided to use .forEach because it was the quickest for me to implement transforming your nested data. Certainly it would be possible to map over vehicles, then map over the files and then flatten the result (up to you!)

Comment: Really appreciate the clarification! Just gave yours a try and oddly enough got an error. Updated the original post with the screenshot. Please take a look.

Comment: actually it rendered beautifully! it was some other error. One last question, how can I be able to multi select the checkboxes and simply console log the information on the row selected? For example, if first row is selected and a console log button is pressed, I want it to console log the information for that particular row. Thanks again lawls544

Comment: @JoKo 1. To enable multi-selection you can add the `multiSelectable={true}` prop to your `<Table>`. 2. You can use the `onRowSelection` prop of `<Table>` to hook into functionality about what rows are selected.  If your original question has been answered, please mark the answer as selected.

Comment: I did give it a try but it console logged incorrectly. Could you show please one last time? Because that was what I was ultimately trying to achieve. Will accept answer right away.

Comment: @JoKo I have edited my answer with an updated example.

Comment: Thank you so much! Same with me when I gave it a try, it is just logging the row number, correct? Sorry if there was miscommunication but I was wondering how to log the information in that particular selected row, such as Start Time, End Time, Type, VIN.

Comment: @JoKo The `onRowSelection` hook just returns the selected row indices. Mapping this back to your original data to get more specific properties is something that you need to take care of.

Comment: any suggestions as to what to look into? Because that's what I was attempting to resolve ultimately.

Comment: @JoKo From the 3rd example, it would map back to the result of lines 48 - 59 in main.js; whatever data is being used in the table.

Comment: Got it really appreciate it lawls544! Accepted the answer and upvoted. I made my attempt and does log but I would have to press twice in order to log it. Is it webpackbin problem? http://www.webpackbin.com/4kOXRc53- Also am I doing it the right way?

Answer (score 0):

Let's tackle these warnings one by one:

For the first warning, you just have to upgrade to v 0.15.4.

For the second and third warnings, as stated, you are putting a `<div>` inside `<tr></tr>` tags and putting vice versa. You may have created a component called FileTableRow that you put inside `<tr></tr>` tags. This FileTableRow may have some render() function like this:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            ... some code here ...
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Yes I have a FileTableRow component that what currently .map returns but with div as a container, because I took out div and it throws an error. Any other way around it?

Comment: Please take a look at the original post with update. Thank you

Comment: I think the TableBody passes properties into its children. So to make this work perfectly, try to pass props to you FileTableRow.