# Composing material table from custom rows

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to wrap each of my rows in table with dedicated component so that it would have structure like

```
<TableBody>
  <MyRow/>
  <MyRow/>
</TableBody>
```

instead of

```
<TableBody>
  <TableRow/>
  <TableRow/>
</TableBody>
```

However, after doing it selection checkbox disappears.

https://jsfiddle.net/uLed8p5u/

Any advices how that could be fixed?

Comment: Please see my answer on another very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39278089/2109514

Comment: @lawls544 thank you. Did put + on that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var MyRow = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return <TableRow {...this.props}>
        {this.props.children[0]}
        <TableRowColumn>2</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn>Randal White</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn>Unemployed</TableRowColumn>
      </TableRow>
      }
});
```

Just needs to have the props re-applied to the child elements in the same way that the TableBody component does.